# Why is drawing bitmaps is very slow on some android 2.2 phones?

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, android-canvas

I have a simple card game where the user can drag and drop cards around the screen. On some of the 2.2 android phones like the Droid and EVO the card drawing is very slow. This is strange because it happens on some of the faster phones. However it's not all phones I test on the Droid and Droid X and the program runs great also runs good on slower phone like the G1. I started getting reports about this after Motorolla released the 2.2 update for the Droid.

Here's the fix I came up with but it really lowers the quality of my graphics. Gradients look horrible.

I changed this

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(newBmp.getWidth(), newBmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

to this

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(newBmp.getWidth(), newBmp.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
```

The problem goes away but the looks suffer. I need to keep the alpha channel so I can't use RGB_565. Is there some way to keep my quality images and not make it run so slow?

Comment: I don't know about Android development, but could it be that some devices use a different native bitmap format? I'd try to use the format which is native to the device, and would expect this to be the fastest.

Comment: I'm using png files. The strange thing is that it will run fine on a Droid with 2.1 but slow on some Droid phones with 2.2. I think this might be a bug but I still need a good work around.

Comment: How large are these cards? Also, where are you getting the Bitmaps from? Are you using them as off-screen buffers? What resolution are the Bitmaps?

Comment: Where are the original image files being stored? in the Raw or image folders? How are they being imported into the project? I use image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.example);

Comment: The default bitmap channel used is different for versions and hardware manufactures. Try setting it to something and test it on both fast and slow devices.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly these are some large `Bitmaps` that you are trying to process.  Have a look at this android training [Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html) .

I think this could help your performance and make loading bitmaps not block the main UI thread.